# U-SQL combine operation from three joins writes a ridiculous amount of data

Tags: sql, azure, azure-data-lake, u-sql

So I have three data sources which I want to join together to produce some output.

**File1.json:** `378mb`

**File2.json:** `72kb`

**file3.json:** `500kb`

```
 @extractFile1 = EXTRACT columnList FROM PATH "path/File1.json" USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();

 @extractFile2 = EXTRACT columnList FROM PATH "path/File2.json" USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();

 @extractFile3 = EXTRACT columnList FROM PATH "path/File3.json" USING new Microsoft.Analytics.Samples.Formats.Json.JsonExtractor();

 @result = 
     SELECT f1.column, f2.column, f1.column, f3.column
     from @extractFile3 AS f3
     INNER JOIN (
              SELECT f3new.column,
                     f3new.column AS somename
                   from @extractFile1 AS f1
                   INNER JOIN @ExtractFile3 f3new ON f1.column == f3new.column
                   GROUP BY f3new.column
            ) AS first 
               ON f3.column == somename

            INNER JOIN @extractFile1 AS f1 ON f3.column == f1.column
            INNER JOIN @extractFile2 as f2 ON f1.column == f3.column
```

Executing this results in the combine operation in the job graph displaying Writes: 195GB, and still going. It has run for 70minutes on one vertex.

Does anyone understand how the combine operation in the execution plan is even able to write that much data?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried turning on the [InputFileGrouping preview feature](https://github.com/Azure/AzureDataLake/blob/master/docs/Release_Notes/2018/2018_Spring/USQL_Release_Notes_2018_Spring.md#input-file-set-uses-less-resources-when-operating-on-many-small-files-is-in-public-preview)? It's dramatically improved performance for me when working with hundreds of small JSON files in ADLA.

Comment: I tried it just now, but the result did not change. The combine operation stille writes an endless amount of data. I will keep this feature in mind for future scenarious where I have many small files, but I do not think it is relevant for my case now, as I only have three relatively small files.